# Argument variable vs. indexed variable in Fourier transform.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics, linearization

Why is  the transformed variable in some fourier transforms written as an index whereas sometimes it is written as an argument ? For example,
    $$G_{\bf k}({\bf{v}},t)= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int g({\bf x},{\bf v},t)exp(-i{\bf k} . {\bf x})d{\bf x} $$

In the example above, why is $\bf k$ not written as a function argument but as an index ?

Comment: Maybe because sometimes you are just considering the Fourier coefficients? hard to tell without a specific example.

Comment: I have edited my question.